# Sitecore SPEAK UI configure ListControl to display icon and button

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-speak-ui

Is there a way in Sitecore SPEAK UI (7.5) to configure a `ListControl` (`ViewMode` set to `DetailList`) to contain a column with images, and another column containing buttons?

I've created a `ListControl Parameters` item beneath my `PageSettings` item and have added a few `ColumnField` items for the required columns - but cant find any other template types to add for different types of column data.  I've also tried playing around with the `Formatter` and `HTMLTemplate` fields of the `ColumnField`s but am not sure how these are meant to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering button means hyperlink. You can try adding the following in the `HTMLTemplate`:

For Image:

```html
<img src="{{YourImageSourceField}}" ..../>
```

For Hyperlink:

```html
<a href="{{YourLinkSrcField}}">{{YourLinkTextField}}</a>
```

You can also consider reading [Martina Welander Speak Series](http://mhwelander.net/category/speak/) for some information on this kind of custom implementations.

Comment: Literally just found the relevant section in the speak component reference at the same time.. Thanks, this is just what I needed.

Comment: @MatthewDresser Sorry I was too late on the response :) Glad it helped you !

Answer (score 1):

I've also used the custom title property of the ListView by setting ViewMode to TileList. Then used Knockout to databind to a custom tile using standard cshtml, if this is any use?

```html
<div class="sc-tile-default" data-bind="attr: {id: Id}">
<div style="min-height: 98px;">
    <img width="112" data-bind="attr: {src: Path}" />
</div>

<div class="sc-iconList-item-title">
    <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
</div>
```

See this project
https://github.com/sobek1985/WallpaperManager

[image: List Control]

Comment: Cool, that's a nice approach as it avoids stuffing too much html markup into a single line text field! I don't see a `ListView` control though (and on my `ListControl` I don't have those properties you mentioned. Are they new to Sitecore 8?

Comment: Just had a check on a Sitecore 7.2 site. It looks like the only View Modes available on Sitecore 7.x is Detail List and Icon List. The TitleList and custom TitleHtmlFile seem to be new features for Sitecore 8 and not in Sitecore 7.5  Sorry about that, I assumed the field was present from 7.5 upwards.